# Can FIFA be played cross-console online?

Tags: fifa-16

My friend has a Xbox one, while I've got an Xbox 360.

Will I be able to play FIFA 16 with him online? Or would I have to get an Xbox One to play with him?

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed impossible to play Fifa 16 on your Xbox 360 vs someone with a Xbox One.

The simple reason for this is that the markets on each console have been separated as of Fifa 16. why?

"Splitting the economies will make it more difficult for coin sellers to move fraudulent coins from one console generation to another."

[Source](https://www.easports.com/uk/fifa/ultimate-team/news/2015/fut-player-experience-faq)

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you cannot do cross-platform gaming quite yet.  Although there is a game on Xbox One that does just that, it's called World of Tanks.  You, as an Xbox 360 player, would be able to play with or against someone on an Xbox One.

So, sorry you would have to buy an Xbox One to play Fifa with your friend.

Comment: Although I've been thinking of this and doing research on it for a while, like if PlayStation players were able to play with Xbox players.  I understand it's an awesome concept and my brother says it wouldn't be **too** hard to do, but whatever, we can't control what game companies choose to do.  Honestly it's mainly about the companies wanting you to buy the all newer game systems so they get monies.

Comment: Shadowrun allowed Xbox 360 players vs. Windows players (via GFWL).  I can't remember if Lost Planet was the same.

Comment: It's an awesome concept.  But people want to make money so it just isn't very popular

Comment: Actually, Xbox and PC compatibility is something Microsoft have been working on, with rumors of PlayStation being added to the compatibility. There are also other titles you can play across generations of Xbox, and it is always possible that EA would enable said feature for Fifa 16, in time.

Comment: @Timelord64 well do keep in mind that I answered this question in November, so that's somewhat new news. :)

Comment: Mostly old news, in November.

Comment: @TrapHappy You are correct. Actually it is very trivial because client-server architectures are client agnostic. To a server, the signals from a ps3, ps4  , xbox360, one, pc are all the same.